# Construct a random vector as a function of another random vector

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-functions

**ASSUMPTION 1**: there exists a continuous random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
p_1=\Pr(X\geq 0, Z\geq 0)\\
p_2=\Pr(Y\geq 0, Z< 0)\\
p_3=\Pr(X< 0, Y<0)\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $(p_1,p_2,p_3)\in [0,1]^3$ and $p_1+p_2+p_3=1$. Further, the marginal distribution of each of $X,Y,Z$ are symmetric around 0.

Note that such a random vector $(X,Y,Z)$ may not exist for some values of $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$. This is why here I **assume** that it exists.

**QUESTION**: Does Assumption 1 imply that there exists (i.e., we can construct from $(X,Y,Z)$) a continuous random vector $(W,H,Q)$ such that:

1. it holds that
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   \Pr(W\geq 0, Q\geq 0)=p_1\\
   \Pr(H\geq 0, Q< 0)= p_2\\
   \Pr(W< 0, H<0)= p_3\\
   \end{cases}
   $$
2. the marginal distribution of each of $W,H,Q$ are symmetric around 0.
3. $Q=W-H$.

---

Note that the map from $(X,Y,Z)$ to $(W,H,Q)$ does not need to be deterministic. For instance, it could be that $W=X+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is another well defined random variable.

---

**SOME DISCUSSION ON THE MOTIVATION BEHIND THE QUESTION:** I have a problem in statistics/computer science where I need to verify the existence of a 3-d distribution function that satisfies constraints 1-3. However, constraint 3 is computationally intractable to implement because   infinite-dimensional. Much simpler is to verify   the existence of a 3-d distribution function that satisfies constraints 1-2 and, then, use the construction I'm investigating about (if it exists!) to conclude about the existence of the originally desired distribution.

---

**ATTEMPTED ANSWER (with questions)**:

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ and $(W,H,Q)$ be defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \Pr)$.

Define $(W,H,Q)$ as follows:

- For each $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $X(\omega)\geq 0$ and $Z(\omega)\geq 0$:

$$\big(W(\omega), H(\omega), Q(\omega)\big)=\big(2X(\omega), X(\omega), X(\omega)\big)$$

- For each $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $Y(\omega)\geq 0$ and $Z(\omega)< 0$:

$$\big(W(\omega), H(\omega), Q(\omega)\big)=\big(Y(\omega), 2Y(\omega), -Y(\omega)\big)$$

- Complete the definition of $(W,H,Q)$ with negative values for $W$ and $H$ in such a way that the marginals are symmetric around zero and that $\Pr(W<0, H<0)=p_3$. Hence, we will need to have: $-2X, -Y$ for $W$; $-X, -2X$ for $H$; $-X, Y$ for $Q$.  I'm not sure we can always do this, though. Can we?

Comment: (i) When you say "construct from", do you mean that $(W,H,Q)$ should be a deterministic function of $(X, Y, Z)$? (ii) in the second line of condition 1 (the equation involving $p_2$), do you really mean $W$ and $Q$? or should that be $H$ and $Q$?

Comment: There was a typo, thanks. The function should not be deterministic.

Comment: @JamesMartin I have added an attempted answer, incomplete and with questions. But, perhaps, it can open the discussion.

Comment: I'm playing around with this, but I'm afraid that the claim is wrong. If you think that the claim is wrong, could you provide a clear counterexample (i.e., give an $(X,Y,Z)$ satisfying Assumption 1, and show that there is no $(W,H,Q)$ satisfying 1-3)? That would help immensely. According to my simulations, the claim seems right, but I can't provide a formal proof and hence I'm thinking that maybe my simulations do not really explore "patological" cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will begin with a reformulation of your question which makes it not only more symmetric, by also (at least for me) more natural and interesting. I will pass from your variables $(W,H,Q)$ to new variables $(X,Y,Z)$ (which are **not** your original $X,Y,Z$) by putting $X=W, Y=-Q, Z=-H$. Then your condition (3) becomes just $X+Y+Z=0$. Therefore you are asking about a probability distribution $\pi$ on the plane
$$\mathcal P=\{x+y+z=0\}\subset\mathbb R^3$$ such that all its one-dimensional marginals are symmetric, and you are interested in the possible values of
$$
\begin{aligned}
p_1=\pi\{x>0, y<0\} \;, \\
p_2=\pi\{y>0, z<0\} \;, \\
p_3=\pi\{z>0,x<0\} \;.
\end{aligned}
$$
Although it's not completely clear to me what is the **continuity** of random vectors you are referring to, I will presume that it implies that the probability $\pi$ of the line $\ell_x=\mathcal P \cap\{x=0\}$ and of the analogous lines $\ell_y,\ell_z\subset\mathcal P$ are all 0, so that replacing non-strict inequalities with strict ones doesn't change anything (the general case can also be treated in pretty much the same way). For a better visualization one can draw a picture of the plane $\mathcal P$ and the lines $\ell_x,\ell_y,\ell_z$ in the coordinates $x,y$ (so that $z=-x-y$).

Since all the domains from the definitions of the numbers $p_i$ are pairwise disjoint, and the complement of their union consists of the zero measure lines $\ell_x,\ell_y,\ell_z$, indeed $\sum p_1=1$. Moreover, the symmetry condition on the marginals means that all numbers $p_i$ satisfy the conditions $p_i\le \frac12$ (and, of course $p_i\ge 0$).

I claim that, conversely, **any collection $(p_i)$ like this can be realized by a measure $\pi$ satisfying the above conditions**. Indeed, take for $\pi$ the distribution with two atoms at the points $(1,-2,1)$ and $(-1,2,-1)$ and the weight $\frac12$. Then the corresponding $p$-vector $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is
$$
v_3 = \left(\tfrac12, \tfrac12, 0\right) \;.
$$
If you want to have an absolutely continuous measure $\pi$ with the same property, you can just smoothen the above distribution by taking the normalized sum of the uniform distributions on, say, side $\varepsilon$ squares centered at $(1,-2)$ and $(-1,2)$ in the coordinates $(x,y)$.

By symmetry, there are also measures $\pi$ with the $p$-vectors $v_2=\left(\tfrac12, 0, \tfrac12\right)$ and $v_1=\left(0, \tfrac12, \tfrac12\right)$. By taking convex combinations of the associated measures $\pi$ one can realize any $p$-vector from the convex hull of $v_1,v_2,v_3$, which is precisely the set determined by the above conditions on $p_i$ (for visualization one can draw a picture in the coordinates $p_1,p_2,1-p_1-p_2$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (1) Is it correct to say that you haven't used Assumption 1 at all? (2) Is it correct to say that you have only used a condition on $p_1, p_2, p_3$ to claim your result? (3) Is the condition that each $p_i\leq 1/2$ necessary and sufficient for your claim or just sufficient?

Comment: (4) Does your initial reformulation change the content of my question or is it just an harmless change of variables?

Comment: (5) I think there a few typos at the end of your answer, e.g. "one can realise AND p-vector ....", which makes it hard for me to understand the conclusion of the proof. Could you check that? Thank you.

Comment: @W13 - (1) yes; (2) I don't understand this question; (3) It is **necessary and sufficient** - this is precisely what the claim in bold states; (4) in addition to changing variables I have also replaced made all inequalities strict (if you wish, the measures assigning non-zero values to the boundary lines can also be dealt with in a similar way); (5) corrected

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in the relation between your claim and Assumption 1: can there be cases where Assumption 1 holds but there is no $\pi$ measure according to your claim? In other words, is the assumption that each $p_i$ is less than $1/2$ also necessary and sufficient for Assumption 1 to hold?

Comment: Also, I don't get from your proof why, if $p_i>1/2$ for some $i=1,2,3$, then there CANNOT be a $\pi$ measure satisfying the desired restrictions. Which step of the proof fails?

Comment: Since your marginals are symmetric, $\pi\{x<0\}=\pi\{x>0\}\ge p_1$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you comment about the relation between Assumption 1 and your claim? In particular, are there cases where Assumption 1 holds but there are no $\pi$ measures according to your claim?

Comment: Don't really know - I don't think there is a natural link between the measures on the plane and on the whole space in your setup

Comment: I don't quite understand what your primary goal is? Didn't you say that you want to produce distributions satisfying (1)-(3)? This is precisely what my answer is about.

Comment: The argument showing that $p_i\le 1/2$ is still valid in the 3-dimensional case, and the domains used in the definition of $p_i$ are still pairwise disjoint. However, their union is **not** the whole space anymore (namely, the points who coordinates all have the same sign are not in this union), so that one can only claim that $\sum p_i\le 1$.

Comment: I am afraid you don't quite understand the situation. I have just explained that your Assumption 1 implies that $p_i\le 1/2$, and in my answer I explained that under this condition there is a distribution with the same $p_i$ that satisfies your conditions (1)-(3)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this question. I cannot put a +1 because I don't have enough points, but I'd like to.

Comment: I have posted a related question in case you could help me once again. Thanks! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408022/measures-on-the-plane-and-on-mathbbr3